# how to create a generic class or type for these three classes in C#

Tags: c#

if I have these three classes:

```
public class PropertyDouble
{
    private double _value;
    public double Value
    { get; set;}
}

public class PropertyInt
{
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    { get; set;}
}

public class PropertyFloat
{
    private float _value;
    public float Value
    { get; set;}
}
```

Is it possible and how to create a single generic class that I can construct it either: Double, Int or Float?

Comment: To do what, how is it going to be used? Please clarify how it can be used. `IConvertible` can always be used for changing such values.

Comment: Also notice that _value in your example doesn't bind to property Value.

Comment: I've edited to make them classes, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 class Property<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Property<T>
{
   private T _value;
   public T Value
   { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: @Aliostad What is a good? What do you think? please give me suggestion.

Comment: Depends what is the usage. As it is shown, it is only Value Types and need to consider boxing, etc.

Comment: Also they are not generic!! I should not be able to use it with say `Property<Stream>` should I?

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
public class PropertyX<T>
{
   public T Value { get; set;}
}
```

[More can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Wrapper<T> where T : struct
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Btw: this class gets more versatile if you remove the value type constraint.